# Which of these is mutually exclusive?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I took a quiz for my statistics/data class and one of the questions was:

**Which of the following pairs of events is mutually exclusive?**

1. Drawing a face card or drawing a queen from a deck of cards
2. Rolling doubles or rolling a total of 6 with two standard dice
3. Spinning a prime number or spinning an even number on a spinner with eight sectors numbered from 1 to 8
4. Rolling a number greater than 3 or rolling an even number with a fair die

I used process of elimination and selected number 3. as my answer. I got it wrong and my teacher said that number 4 is the correct answer. Unfortunately, the class is all online so I didn't really understand his explanation as well as I would have in an in-person class.

Can someone explain how number 4 is a mutually exclusive event? I would assume that you can roll a number greater than 3 and an even number at the same time.

Comment: As a smart-aleck answer, we were only told the die in #4 was fair but we weren't told the die was a standard die.  Maybe the faces on the die were all odd or maybe the die was a three-sided die.  (*This is meant mostly as a joke, it is far too common for people when referring to a die or dice without further qualification to mean a standard six-sided die with faces labeled $1,2,\dots,6$.  If a more exotic die is intended, additional qualification must be used by the question writer to avoid confusion.  Still, you should be aware of the fact that more exotic dice exist*)

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, none of these are mutually exclusive pairs of events. Their intersections are, in order: drawing a queen of any suit, rolling $(3, 3)$, spinning a $2$, and rolling either a 4 or a 6. Either you have copied the problem incorrectly, or the problem (and thus necessarily your teacher's explanation) is wrong.

Comment: I copy-pasted it straight from the quiz answers so I guess the question is wrong. A lot of students questioned him but he just told us to read it again with an emphasis on the "or". Thanks for the help.